# How to add a custom View inside another custom View?

Tags: android, graphics, android-view, android-custom-view

I have a custom view and want to add one more custom view on that custom view. This is my custom view class:

```
public class CustomCircle extends View{

float radius;
Paint paint = new Paint();

String message = "";
public CustomCircle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2,radius, paint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean isClickInCircle = false;
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    double check = Math.sqrt((x-getWidth()/2)*(x-getWidth()/2) + (y-getHeight()/2)*(y-getHeight()/2));
    if (check<=radius) {
        isClickInCircle= true;
    }
    if (isClickInCircle) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            Toast.makeText(getContext(),message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

and am using another class that extends `LinearLayout`:

```
public class B extends LinearLayout {

private Paint paint;

public B(Context context) {
    super(context);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
}

public void addCircle() {

    CustomCircle circleBlue = new CustomCircle(getContext(), null);
    circleBlue.paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    circleBlue.paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    circleBlue.radius = 160;
    circleBlue.message = "Clicked";
    addView(circleBlue);

    CustomCircle circleRed = new CustomCircle(getContext(), null);
    circleRed.paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    circleRed.paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    circleRed.radius = 80;
    circleRed.message = "Clicked";
    addView(circleRed);

}
```

and I'm calling the B class from the main activity class using :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    B root = new B(this);
    root.addCircle();
    setContentView(root);
}
```

The output is showing me only one circle instead of a circle inside another circle. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

> And the Output is showing me only One circle instead of circle inside
>   circle.

You picked the wrong layout if you want to overlap children, a `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` is the way to go. Also, regarding your code:

```
public class B extends RelativeLayout {
//...
public void addCircle() {

    // the constructor that uses the AttributeSet should be added if you use the 
    // custom component in the xml layout
    CustomCircle circleBlue = new CustomCircle(getContext());
    // ...
    // add it with LayoutParams
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    addView(circleBlue, rlp);
    // the same for the other view
}
```

Also your two circle will have the same dimensions so they will overlap perfectly(and you'll not be able to see them), you would need to give them different dimensions, through the `LayoutParams`, for example:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
```

for the first one and:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
```

for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there are 2 circles in the layout but you can see only one
because it has the same color as the first circle and they are laying on top of each other?

change `circleRed.paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);`
to `circleRed.paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);`
and see what it gives

Comment: Yes i changed circleRed.paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); Still its displaying me one circle.

Comment: than i would suggest looking at @Luksprog answer

Comment: So swap the colours.  What do you see now?  If the colour of the circle you see is also swapped, then you have 2 circles exactly overlaying each other.